# How to find datatype of all the fields in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I have a doc

```
{_id:NumberLong(1),gender:"M",vip:false}.
```

How to extract the type of individual field in Mongo with a query..
How to use typeof operator:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
> db.test.findOne()
{ "_id" : NumberLong(1), "gender" : "M", "vip" : false }
> db.test.findOne().gender
M
> typeof db.test.findOne().gender
string
```

Answer (score 6):

Question title asks for all fields and answers tell how to make it with one field. Here's an all document fields approach (just change *your_collection* part at the beginning):

```
[db.your_collection.findOne()].forEach( function(my_doc) { for (var key in my_doc) { print(key + ': ' + typeof my_doc[key]) } } )
```

First you get an document from the collection, then convert it to an array with [] so we can apply a function with forEach, and finally in the function we iterate over the document fields to print their key and type as we want. This should output something like:

```
_id: object
gender: string
vip: boolean
```

Comment: these are javascript representation of types not actual mongodb types

Comment: In the command prompt (mongo prompt) it works like a charm. Splendid!!

Answer (score 1):

You can for example query the type of `gender` field:

```
typeof db.getCollection('your_collection').findOne({"_id": NumberLong(1)}).gender
```